# In Java, when using bitshifts, why does 1 << 32 != 1 << 31 << 1?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

```java
int a = 1 << 32;
int b = 1 << 31 << 1;
```

Why does `a == 1`? `b` is 0 as I expected.

Comment: A related (*not* duplicate) question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644708/why-use-only-the-lower-five-bits-of-the-shift-operand-when-shifting-a-32-bit-valu

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All shifts are done mod 32 for ints and mod 64 for longs.

From [section 15.19 of the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand
>   operand is `int`, only the five
>   lowest-order bits of the right-hand
>   operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand
>   operand were subjected to a bitwise
>   logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with
>   the mask value 0x1f. The shift
>   distance actually used is therefore
>   always in the range 0 to 31,
>   inclusive.
>
> If the promoted type of the left-hand
>   operand is `long`, then only the six
>   lowest-order bits of the right-hand
>   operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand
>   operand were subjected to a bitwise
>   logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with
>   the mask value 0x3f. The shift
>   distance actually used is therefore
>   always in the range 0 to 63,
>   inclusive.

As for *why* the language was designed that way - I don't know, but C# has the same design decision. Here's what the annotated ECMA C# spec says:

> C# deliberately keeps
>   implementation-defined behaviors to a
>   miinimum. They are accepted only when
>   the performance impact of forcing
>   uniform behavior would be excessive
>   (such as for some floating-point
>   precision issues). Hence, the size of
>   each integral type is precisely
>   specified, and the character set is
>   fixed to Unicode.
>
> For shift operations, too, uniform
>   behavior is specified. It can be
>   achieved using a single extra
>   instruction (& 0x1F or & 0x3F) that
>   incurs only a tiny cost on modern
>   processors, especially since it does
>   not reference memory. Unlike for
>   floating-point operations, the
>   difference in shift behavior would be
>   dramatic if left to the whim of the
>   processors; rather than a small
>   difference in precision, completely
>   different integral results would be
>   produced.
>
> In making this decision the committe
>   studied reference materials for a
>   number of different processor
>   architectures. There is little
>   consistency in the behavior for shift
>   counts outside the range -32..+32 for
>   32-bit operands, and respectively
>   -64..+64 for 64-bit operands.

(There's then a list of some examples.)

This seems an entirely reasonable explanation to me. Consistency is definitely important, and if it would be impossible to implement *different* consistent behaviour in a performant way on some systems, I think this is a reasonable solution.

Comment: I suppose it is because it is quite pointless to shift an int of 32 bits: the result will be always 0, no?

Comment: Well, the situation would arise when the amount you want to shift by is say, an user defined variable. So yes, it should just zero the number, but I don't want to insert a check just for the 32 bit case.

Comment: It is reasonable, but I guess it's not mentioned very often (It's in the spec's, but not Sun's tutorial page for shifts.)

Comment: Wow.  You learn something new every day.  Weird design decision.

Answer (score 0):

There is some difference in how processors implement shift instructions.

For instance, IIRC, ARM processors (32-bit ISA) take the least significant byte of the shifting register. (Shifts are not actually standalone instructions on ARM).

So long as the underlying processor has a vaguely sensible way to shift, it's easier to clear all but the least significant bits (one instruction usually) than to check if the shift is large and branch (actually on the ARM this only typically adds one instruction because all instructions are conditional).