# C: Setting the i'th bit of an integer to 1 in O(1)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, time-complexity, bitwise-operators, bit

Now, I know the way to set the i'th bit of a number is use the shift operator to shift 1 till you reach the required bit, and then just or it with the number.
But this process is O(length of number) because shifting a number to the i'th position is like traversing until there, right?
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is my code:

```
x = x| (1<<i)
```

Is there a way to do this in O(1)?
In other words, how does one get direct access to the bits in a number?
I'm thinking along the lines of array indexing.

Comment: I think you are wrong. This operation is O( 1 ).

Comment: It depends on your hardware, i.e. CPU. Show your code and the **relevant** machine code. But you can use a lookup-table to be on the safe (but possibly slower) side.

Comment: How is this operation O(1)? It will have to go traverse the number, right?

Comment: No, you can just use `1<<i` to get the i'th bit

Comment: `n |= 1 << i`, like this?

Comment: @Tinkidinki There is no need to traverse the number. The shift operation usually requires one low-level command

Comment: Just use it as you have it. I dont see why it should not be 0(1) operation. There is no loop or whatever. Also on some cpus or microcontrollers this line is converted into single instruction.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, so I am to understand that shifting 1 how many ever positions is always O(1) and doesnt depend on i at all?

Comment: @Tinkidinki i think so.

Comment: @Tinkidinki yes. For more bits operations also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c?rq=1

Comment: Bit shift is O(1), just like addition is O(1). When adding *n* to *m*, you don't have to increment *m* *n* times. The same goes with bit shifting.

Comment: @el.pescado, thanks for the anology, that makes a lot of sense to me!!!

Comment: Definitive answers are inherently wrong because all this depends on is *your definition* of what the elementary operations are. Sure, bit shifts by a variable amount are commonly accepted as elementary, but it's always a choice that you make, even if you do it implicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shifting `1` by `k` bits is done in hardware. At a grossly simplified level, an `n`-bit CPU has `n` registers that represent a number shifted by 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1 bits in each direction. When a shift operation is executed, CPU loads the number in a register `k` based on the number of shifts, and reads the output in the next cycle. This makes bit shifting an O(1) operation.

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10935310/335858) has a diagram explaining the hardware behind the O(1) "magic" of modern CPUs using multiplexers.

Comment: Thanks!!! but from the diagram, i infer that for a 2^i bit system, i need i layers of circuitry, right? So shift is done in constant time for a given system.

Comment: @Tinkidinki Yes, barrel shifter needs `i` layers for 2^i-bit system. However, all `i` layers are active at the same time, so even though we are talking about `i` gate delays, the operation completes in a single cycle (which is, of course, much longer than gate delays).

Comment: Not all processors have barrel shifter... P4 didn't.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out `n |= 1 << i` is *not* O(n). This is because a bit shift operation in most CPU's is a single instruction, on the ones I am familiar with at the moment it takes a cycle or two IIRC.

If however, you are introducing a loop within your C code, then this of course, will be O(n), such as:

```
n = 1;
for(j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    n <<= 1;
x |= n;
```

For a refactored bit setting for generically setting a bit in an integer value, you could do something like:

```
typedef enum x_bits_e {
    x_bit1 = 1 << 0;
    x_bit2 = 1 << 1;
    x_bit3 = 1 << 2; 
     // and so on
};

int16_t set_bit_in_x(int16 x, x_bits_e i)
{ 
    return x | i;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the down-vote?

Comment: No problem. I can up-vote your answer.:)

Comment: i didnt, but you could improve naming somehow

Comment: Ha, thanks @VladfromMoscow, really just curious as to how specifically the answer could be improved tbh

Comment: P4 didn't have a barrel shifter